# Attempting to use mod_pagespeed on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, arch-linux

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Disclaimer: I'm not very experienced with linux/apache, or just about anything involved.

I'm trying to use mod_pagespeed on Arch Linux; there is no binary available, but I was able to install it with yaourt from AUR.

Now, the pagespeed module exists /etc/httpd/modules, and there is a configuration file here: /etc/httpd/conf/extra/pagespeed.conf.

But the module is not actually loading or functioning, which I can tell by capturing the headers when requesting a page from the running apache server.

I feel like I likely need to modify httpd.conf in some way to load the module, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how. It looks like all the config is in the aforementioned pagespeed.conf file, but is that even being loaded? Doesn't seem so; unless it's just not working.

Any tips at all would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You indeed need to enable the module with the [LoadModule directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule). Search for other instances of that directive in your config and add one that loads mod_pagespeed. More details about configuring apache can be found on [google's documentation site](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration), this bit is also explained there.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have it figured. My only confusion was that the provided configuration file already had the loadModule directive, so I didn't think I should add it directly to httpd.conf. I've added an "include" statement to bring in the config file and all is well.